# (tensorflow) uavbilgi@uavbilgi-Lenovo-G500:~$ pip install --ignore-installed --upgrade TF_PYTHON_URL

Tags: python-3.x, ubuntu, tensorflow

When I write this code on terminal "(tensorflow) uavbilgi@uavbilgi-Lenovo-G500:~$ pip install --ignore-installed --upgrade TF_PYTHON_URL" I am faced with errors:
Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement TF_PYTHON_URL (from versions: )
No matching distribution found for TF_PYTHON_URL

what should I do?

Answer (score 0):

The [Linux installation instructions for TensorFlow](https://www.tensorflow.org/install/install_linux) use `TF_PYTHON_URL` as a placeholder for a URL:

> 5. (Optional) If Step 4 failed (typically because you invoked a pip version lower than 8.1), install TensorFlow in the active virtualenv environment by issuing a command of the following format:
>
>    ```
>    (tensorflow)$ pip install --upgrade TF_PYTHON_URL   # Python 2.7
>    (tensorflow)$ pip3 install --upgrade TF_PYTHON_URL  # Python 3.N
>    ```
>
>    where TF_PYTHON_URL identifies the URL of the TensorFlow Python package. The appropriate value of TF_PYTHON_URL depends on the operating system, Python version, and GPU support. Find the appropriate value for TF_PYTHON_URL for your system here. For example, if you are installing TensorFlow for Linux, Python 2.7, and CPU-only support, issue the following command to install TensorFlow in the active virtualenv environment:
>
>    ```
>    (tensorflow)$ pip3 install --upgrade \
>     https://storage.googleapis.com/tensorflow/linux/cpu/tensorflow-1.1.0-cp34-cp34m-linux_x86_64.whl
>    ```

Therefore, you should replace `TF_PYTHON_URL` with the appropriate URL for the package that you are trying to install.

Note that you may simply be able to use `pip install tensorflow` or `pip install tensorflow-gpu` to install the correct PIP package, and it is only necessary to specify a package URL if you have an old version of PIP installed.